# Agregar un año de diferencia en un input date al seleccionar una fecha

Tags: javascript, html, date

Tengo dos *input date*, en uno selecciono la fecha por ejemplo de hoy `17/10/2019` y quiero que en el segundo *input* que es el de fecha de corte me ponga en automático la fecha de un año después.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="inputText">*Fecha Activacion</div>
      <input type="date" name="fecha" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="inputText">*Fecha de corte</div>
      <input type="date" name="fecha_cor" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" readonly required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolverlo primero ponles un `id` a los `<input>`, luego le agregas un *listener* al primero para que cuando se cambie la fecha de este, se modifique también la fecha del segundo, y para que la fecha de este ultimo sea de un año después le sumas 1 al valor del año:

```js
var fecha1 = document.getElementById('fecha');
var fecha2 = document.getElementById('fecha_cor');
  
  fecha1.addEventListener('change', () => {
    nuevaFecha = fecha1.value.split('-');
    nuevaFecha[0]++; 
    fecha2.value=nuevaFecha.join('-');
  });
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="inputText">*Fecha Activacion</div>
      <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="inputText">*Fecha de corte</div>
      <input type="date" id="fecha_cor" name="fecha_cor" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="date" readonly required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo.